# Multiple endpoints for a single model in REST framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a REST framework app for a multi-page form:

```
class InformationRequest(models.Model):
  # user information
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
  # contact details
  phone = models.CharField(max_length=60)
  email = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

I'm trying to create endpoints for each of the two blocks of data within the model:

```
UserInformationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=60)
  last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=60)

ContactDetailsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  phone = serializers.CharField(max_length=60)
  email = serializers.CharField(max_length=60)
```

I'd like the endpoints to look like:

```
requests/1/user-informtion
requests/1/contact-details
```

But I'm unsure of how to structure the view to achieve this. Currently I'm using a model viewset:

```
class InformationRequestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = InformationRequest.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ??
```

Is it possible to have two serializers for one model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible to have 2 (or any number of) serializers for a model. And you are on the right path. What you want is different urls mapping to different views. So in your case, it can be something like the following:

Note that I turned each of your serializers into a [`ModelSerializer`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer).

## path-to/serializers.py

```
class UserInformationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = InformationRequest
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')

class ContactDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = InformationRequest
        fields = ('phone', 'email')
```

Next, we have 2 different urls that point to 2 different views:

## path-to/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^requests/(?P<pk>\d+)/user-information/$', views.UserInformationDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^requests/(?P<pk>\d+)/contact-details/$', views.ContactInformationDetail.as_view()),
# ... other urls
]
```

And finally, the views themselves (I'm using generic [`RetrieveAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview) for convenience)

## path-to/views.py

```
class UserInformationDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = InformationRequest.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserInformationSerializer

class ContactInformationDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = InformationRequest.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactDetailsSerializer
```